# Optimizing Perplexity or Log-Likelihood for Topic Counts in PySpark's LDA

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lda, topic-modeling

I am trying to use PySpark to identify a "good" number of topics in some dataset (e.g., tweets), and several ways exist to do this task (see [here](https://www.quora.com/Latent-Dirichlet-Allocation-LDA-What-is-the-best-way-to-determine-k-number-of-topics-in-topic-modeling) for examples).

My question though is about the values reported by PySpark's logPerplexity and logLikelihood functions accompanying pyspark.ml.clustering.LDA. My understanding says that, as I increase topic counts, I should see perplexity decrease and the log likelihood value increase. I see this behavior in gensim using the same model parameters.

In PySpark, however, as I increase the topics, values returned by log-perplexity *increase*, and log-likelihood *decreases*. These results seem counter to my understanding of what these values mean.

Am I missing some fundamental aspect of PySpark's LDA model? Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've included a copy of the Jupyter notebook I'm using to run these tests, so you can see my results.

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~cbuntain/FindTopicK-pyspark-regex.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any answer to this? I started working with LDA in pyspark and I will start exploring this same problem. Do you have the code in gensim so I can try it as well with my data?

Comment: Nope, no answer from the Spark mailing list or here. I ended up doing my analysis in Gensim, as you might imagine. I don't have that code published though.